# How to prove that $\exists c_1,c_2>0, F(t)\geq c_1 |t|^{\theta}-c_2$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

I have the following condition:

$$
0\leq \theta F(t)<t f(t), \quad \forall t>0
$$
where$$
F(t)=\int_0^t f(s) \,\mathrm{d}s.
$$

with $\theta>0$

I want to prove that $\exists c_1,c_2>0$, such that$$F(t)\geq c_1 |t|^{\theta}-c_2.$$

I ued the condition and I just found this 
$$F(t) > \frac{F(t_0)}{t_0^\theta} t^\theta. \quad t>t_0>0$$

I say that as $$\frac{F(t_0)}{t_0^\theta} t^\theta>0,$$ then the inequality is right for any $c_2>0$.

Is is true? Or I can found $c_2$ directly from the condition ?

Thank you.